# how to run lower PHP version code (codeigniter) into higher php version

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, backwards-compatibility

I am using CodeIgniter version 3.1.6. And I am using two types of PHP version codeings.

First one is PHP 5.6.35 and another one is 7.1.16. I use PHP 7.1.16 to use Apache Solr.

But the PHP 5.6.35 version support coding is not working if PHP version is 7.1.16. And the PHP 7.1.16 coding is not working in PHP 5.6.35.

I can't change CodeIgniter version, because totally 80% work depend on lower version. At the same time I need PHP higher version codeings also.

Now my question is if it is possible to run lower PHP version code into higher PHP version.

Comment: If you told us which problems you have we could suggest some polyfills maybe.

Comment: My problem is my full project i written in php 5.6.35 version. I want solr search option, but it is working fine in php version 7.1.*.  So if use php 5.6.35 the solr doesnot support. Incase I use 7.1.16 my major part of the project is not working. What I can do now?

Comment: "Is not working" is a really broad description. Why not fix whatever is not working? There are pretty good upgrade notes out there that tell you how to fix such problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that there are certain functions that have simply been removed in the newer version of PHP. If you really need to use a newer PHP version, your only option is to get a migration guide and to rewrite the functions that have become deprecated or have been removed.

You could do that like this:

```
if (!function_exists('removed_function')) {
    function removed_function($params)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In a guide like the below link specifies, you can find what has changed and what functions you'll need to rewrite.

[PHP Migration guide](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php)

Comment: I like to add some points to my querry. If I use higher version php the brwser shows this error `( ! ) Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\project_folder\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php on line 305`

Comment: and

`( ! ) Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\project\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 1`.

Comment: Have you tried raising the memory limit by using `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');` ?

Comment: No.I did not try this.

Comment: You can do this in PHP by using `ini_set` or you could edit your `php.ini` file. Either of those should fix your memory issue.